# R methods for custom S3 class

Tags: r, class, oop, methods

I have my s3 class student

```
# a constructor function for the "student" class
student <- function(n,a,g) {
  # we can add our own integrity checks
  if(g>4 || g<0)  stop("GPA must be between 0 and 4")
  value <- list(name = n, age = a, GPA = g)
  # class can be set using class() or attr() function
  attr(value, "class") <- "student"
  value
}
stud <- student("name", 10, 3.5)
```

Now I would like to create a method similar to `stud.doubleGPA()` which would double the GPA of the student. I know I can achieve this using

```
stud$GPA <- stud$GPA*2
stud$GPA # 7
```

However trying to define a function doesn't seem to work.

```
doubleGPA <- function(student) {
  if(!class(student)=="student") stop("nope")
  student$GPA <- student$GPA*2
}
doubleGPA(stud)
stud$GPA # 7 again (didn't work)
```

And replacing `<-` with `<<-` in the above function gives

```
Error in student$GPA <<- student$GPA * 2 : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

How can I define such a method which would **belong** to an s3 class and therefore be inherited by children ?

Cheers

Comment: You should *almost never* use a test like `if(!class(student)=="student")`.  Classes in S3 are character vectors, so the result of `class(student)=="student"` might be `c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)`, not suitable to use in an `if` condition.  Use `inherits(student, "student")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking of a different kind of object oriented programming than the S3 style, something more like C++ or Java.  You can do that in R, just not in the S3 system.

In the S3 system, methods "belong to" generic functions, not to classes.  Like most functions in R, generic functions don't modify their arguments, they calculate new values and return those.  So you might define a generic function `doubleGPA()`, and have it work on the `"student"` class using

```
doubleGPA <- function(x) UseMethod("doubleGPA")

doubleGPA.student <- function(x) {
  x$GPA <- x$GPA*2
  x
}
```

and then use it as

```
stud <- student("name", 10, 3.5)
stud <- doubleGPA(stud)
```

If you actually want something more like C++ or Java, there are a couple of choices:  "reference classes" from the `methods` package (see `?methods::setRefClass`) and "R6 classes" from the `R6` package.  There are also several prototype-based styles in packages `proto`, `ggplot2`, `R.oo`, and are probably more that I've forgotten to mention.

Comment: and i suppose that this method would also work on children classes of student. why is s3 the recommended way to do oop in r ? Other paradigms seem to be closer to classical oop like say in python

Comment: S3 doesn't really do inheritance, but yes, if the class of an object was `c("foo", "student")` and there was no `doubleGPA.foo` method, `doubleGPA` would dispatch to the `"student"` method.  If there was a `doubleGPA.foo` method, it could call `NextMethod` to do the same.

Comment: Created another related question if you'd like to check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65461117/r-s3-methods-on-classes-within-classes